# How to connect mySql database to a flutter app?

Tags: android, mysql, flutter

I have a mySql database that has many tables, and hava a flutter app I want to show data in it, but I don't need to make an api or any json files, so what is the best way to do it?

Comment: According to my opinion no there is no way to achieve that. But what you can do is use sqflite and work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SQFlite package. There is a link: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite.